# How to get the DatavalueField of a specific DataTextFied in asp:dropdownlist.?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, c3.js

This is the dropdownlist where I bind "Name" .

```
        public void BindDLL()
        {
            functcheck();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, (ID + '-' + Name) AS IDNAME FROM Register";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            ddl_BO.DataSource = dt;

            ddl_BO.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddl_BO.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddl_BO.DataBind();
            ddl_BO.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "-1"));
            ddl_BO.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#dfe6e8");

                   }      

        }
```

I want the "ID" of  "Name" when I click particular name on Dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

The [SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property of DropDownList will give you the id, To get the selected values when user changes the selection you may need to Set AutoPostBack property to true and subscribe [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of DropDownList

```
var id = ddl_BO.SelectedValue;
```

[DropDownList.SelectedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the value of the selected item in the list control, or selects
>   the item in the list control that contains the specified value

Comment: I tried  "SelectedValue" property also. But it gives "Name". suppose ID=74 and Name=Abdul. when I click on Dropdown it shows "Abdul" in variable "id"

Comment: Try using SelectedItem.Value

Comment: Debug and see what you have in datatable?